# Why does Android Studio enter the full path for some classes?

Tags: android-studio

I have the following code for creating a custom adapter and android studio is defaulting to the full path of my package. This was not always like this. I wonder what has changed. And it doesn't know what `localNetView` is even though is declare at the top of my class. Why does Android Studio do it like this? Without making any changes can't find the classes.

```
private ListView localNetListView;
private Adapter localNetAdapter;

localNetListView  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.local_network);
localNetAdapter = new org.pctechtips.netdroid.HostAdapter(this, R.layout.list_main, localIfaceInfo);
localNetListView.setAdapter(localNetAdapter);
```

Comment: The reason is, You might already have `HostAdapter` class in your source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the "Use fully qualified class names" option under File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Imports tab is unchecked.

If this is only happening to a file, check the imports manually and see if another class with the same name (and different package) is imported, and remove its import line.

Comment: it is checked... other classes are not experiencing this problem

Comment: You need to uncheck it.

Comment: thanks... the long path still there. but at least works now

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. That line exists either because it's been previously added (and needs to be fixed manually) or another import for that class already exists. Either way, manual fixing needs to be done.

Comment: Please do let me know If my answer needs anything to be completed.