# Android Studio doesn't autocomplete imports propertly

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have an Android project (I'll update soon with the source once public) that has code in Kotlin.

When I try to import a class it shows on the auto-complete but then it does a full name reference instead of adding the reference to the class on the imports of the file. Also, when I try to do an import, there is no option to include the import to the class.

[image: Auto-import]

It's happened so far in two projects I've worked on. The first one had a mix of Java a Kotlin and I thought that may be the issue, however, the last one doesn't have any Java code.

The code is in the debug configuration. However, a file that is on the same package and folder as this one with the issue doesn't seem to have the same problem and imports work as expected.

## **Update after duplication suggestion**

This was marked as a duplicate, but it's not for several reasons:

- This one involves Kotlin and not Java
- The reported problem was with project imports, this is a library (system) import
- Tried the suggested solution and it doesn't solve this issue.
- This one has a gif ^_^

Comment: Have you tried `Invalidate Caches/Restart` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why android studio enters full path for some of my classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499962/why-android-studio-enters-full-path-for-some-of-my-classes)

Comment: @amine yeah, I've tried all the possible ways 9f restarting, even my laptop. It happens to somebody else working on the same project but on a different computer (and country)

Comment: @Zoe I've updated my question with a couple of reasons why this is not a duplicate. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score -1):

Best what you can do it build new **Empty Project** and copy old classes and files on new project.